# Mutidimensional Clustering of Booleans

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, multidimensional-array

Here is my problem scenario:

I have a few thousand objects. Each object has 256 Boolean dimensions (true or false). I want to find clusters such that

1. Each cluster has a minimum amount of true dimensions (a dimension of a cluster is true iff any object in that cluster has this dimension market as true).
2. The overall sum of all true dimensions over all clusters is minimal.
3. Each cluster is not bigger than a certain predefined value.

The optimality of the solution is not required, however the algorithm should be fast.

How should I best approach this problem? Is there an algorithm that you would recommend?

---

Note: I already implemented a brute force approach to this problem, but it is quite slow.

Comment: Does point 1 mean each cluster must have at least some fixed number of true dimensions, or that each cluster must have as small a number of true dimensions as possible? If you have a functional, but slow, implementation perhaps you should provide a small example, with much fewer dimensions.

Comment: It means each cluster should have as few true dimensions as possible. I just noticed that it might be a bit redundant. Just 2 and 3 should be enough to define the problem. The brute force is basically like this: 1) Find not clustered object with fewest true dimensions and add to new cluster (current cluster) 2) Find most similar, not clustered object (to current cluster) and add. Repeat until current cluster is full 3) Go to 1) if there are more not clustered objects

Comment: My intuition is that you should begin with objects with the most true dimensions. Once you have put one of those in a cluster, there are a lot of other objects that you can add free of cost, because their true dimensions are a subset of the first object's. The objects with few true dimensions can be put almost anywhere there is space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this as a **[mixed-integer linear program (MILP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns)**:

You have a fixed amount of clusters and objects.
Each cluster can have at most 256 true dimensions.
Parameter [image: D_{k,j}] is equal to 1 if dimension i is true in object k.

You have the following **variables**:

1. [image: d_{i,j}] is a binary variable equal to 1 if dimension j is a true dimension of cluster i.
2. [image: o_{i,k}] is a binary variable that is true if object k is in cluster i.

You have the following **constraints**:

1. Each object can be in only one cluster
2. A dimension is true in cluster iif it is true in all objects inside cluster
3. Each cluster can only hold M objects

The second constraint is a tricky one because it doesn't *feel* linear, but actually you *can* write it linearly.
The **constraints** can be written as:

1. [image: C1] for all k
2. [image: C2] for all i and j
3. [image: C3] for all i

The **objective function** can be the sum of all [image: d_{i,j}], so you minimize the overall sum of all true dimensions over all clusters.

Let me explain the **second constraint**: on the right-hand-side, you compute the number of elements inside cluster i, minus the number of objects having dimension j set to one. This is equal to zero if all objects have dimension j, or something positive if not.

If this evaluates to zero, then [image: d_{i,j}] **must** be equal to one to avoid violating the constraint. If not, [image: d_{i,j}] can be anything (zero or one). This works because [image: d_{i,j}] will appear in the objective function, which means that when the program has the choice between zero or one, it will choose zero.

Once you write this up, you can solve it using a commercial solver (if you have one, they give free licenses to students, in case you are one) or [Coin-OR](http://www.coin-or.org/) just to name one.

Just as a reminder: solving MILPs is an **NP-complete problem**.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding with "A dimension is true in cluster iif it is true in all objects inside cluster". That should be "A dimension is false in cluster iff it is false in all objects inside cluster". But that's a very nice idea in general. Thank you! Will mark it accepted once I have the time to verify!

Comment: In that case the second constraint should be d_i,j < sum of o_i,k*D_k,j / N, where N is the number of objects. This sum will always be between zero or one. If one of the D_k,j is equal to one then it will force d_i,j to be equal to one too.

Comment: I developed a (theoretical) solution using Simplex. Unfortunately it has ~371 000 vars and ~1 300 000 rows. I think that's a bit much for any solver.

Comment: @aZen that *is* very big, especially if you have binary variables :( did you try to solve a relaxed problem, i.e. where the binary variables are treated as continuous? there are some very good solvers out there, you should try them out.

Comment: Posted my solution @alestanis. I don't think there is a way to make it feasible. Do you have a suggestion how to approximate it efficiently? The true-dimension-difference-count between objects is a metric, so I was thinking to cluster the objects according to that.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to write down the (theoretical) solution I came up with. Partly because it might help me (see below for more on this) and partly to have a decent solution for anyone interested. It's a system of linear equations that one could solve by using the [Simplex Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).

The constrains I came up with are:

---

> 1) Every object is in exactly one cluster
>
> 2) Every cluster has at most M (*constant*) objects
>
> 3) A dimension of a cluster is true iff at least one of the objects in that cluster has that dimension set as true

---

I will explain how the constrains are enforces now:

Let there be n objects and k clusters. We consider the sum (in the following this is one row)

> x<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup> + x<sub>2</sub><sup>1</sup> + x<sub>3</sub><sup>1</sup> + ... + x<sub>n</sub><sup>1</sup> + d<sub>1</sub><sup>1</sup> + d<sub>2</sub><sup>1</sup> + d<sub>3</sub><sup>1</sup> + ... + d<sub>n</sub><sup>1</sup> +
>
> x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + x<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> + d<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + d<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + d<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + d<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> +
>
> ...
>
> x<sub>1</sub><sup>k</sup> + x<sub>2</sub><sup>k</sup> + x<sub>3</sub><sup>k</sup> + ... + x<sub>n</sub><sup>k</sup> + d<sub>1</sub><sup>k</sup> + d<sub>2</sub><sup>k</sup> + d<sub>3</sub><sup>k</sup> + ... + d<sub>n</sub><sup>k</sup>

where

> x<sub>a</sub><sup>c</sup> is true iff object a is int cluster c
>
> d<sub>b</sub><sup>c</sup> is true iff the dimension b in cluster c is true

Since it is always better (or at least never harmful) to cluster objects, we know the number of clusters is *ceil(objects divided by M)*. For simplicity I will leave out the variables now and just write the coefficients.

**1)** Every object is in exactly one cluster

> 10...0 0...0 10...0 0...0 10...0 0...0 ... 10...0 0...0 = 1
>
> 010...0 0...0 010...0 0...0 010...0 0...0 ... 010...0 0...0 = 1
>
> ...
>
> 0..01 0...0 0...01 0...0 0...01 0...0 ... 0...01 0...0 = 1

This will enforce every object to be in exactly one cluster. This could theoretical allow the objects to be with parts (<1) in several clusters. But because we are looking for the optimal solution this will not happen.

**2)** Every cluster has at most M (*constant*) objects

> 11...1 0...0 0...0 0...0 0...0 0...0 ... 0...0 0...0 <= M
>
> 0...0 0...0 11...1 0...0 0...0 0...0 ... 0...0 0...0 <= M
>
> ...
>
> 0...0 0...0 0...0 0...0 0...0 0...0 ... 11...1 0...0 <= M

The sum of objects is not bigger than M. This constrain should be clear.

Now comes the tricky part:

**3)** A dimension of a cluster is true iff at least one of the objects in that cluster has that dimension set as true

For every dimension and every cluster consider those elements that have this dimension set to true (we could also consider the false one, but they don't matter). We now write a line for each of them (and each cluster)

> 0..010...0 -10...0 0...0 0...0 ... 0...0 0...0 <= 0

where the 1 denotes that this dimension for this object (in this cluster) is set to true and the -1 one identifies the dimension (in this case the first one). If the object is set in this cluster, the dimension for this cluster has to be 1 (1*1 -1*d <= 0), if it's not set the dimension can also be zero (0*1 - 1*d <= 0).

For the second dimension in the first cluster this would look like this:

> 0..010...0 0-10...0 0...0 0...0 ... 0...0 0...0 <= 0

and for the last cluster and the last dimension like this

> 0...0 0...0 0...0 0...0 ... 0..010..0 0...0-1 <= 0

Now we can simply minimize the sum of the x<sub>a</sub><sup>c</sup> and we are done.

*This could probably be written down in a better way, but I hope it's understandable.*

---

Now the problem is the following:
I'm working with 70 clusters, 3000 objects and 2300 dimensions. Using the approach above this results in 371000 variables (clusters * objects + clusters * dimensions) and 1292095 rows (estimating rows as objects + cluster + dimensions * log(objects) * clusters)

I'm tending to believe that the optimal solution is not feasible. Even if you can still optimize the approach described here, it is unlikely that a similar approach will perform much better. So now I'm looking for good approximations, any ideas how to tackle this problem are welcome.

Thank you :)